# text index required for $text query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an error "text index required for $text query". But as I see i made all correctly.

```
const JobSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  jobTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    text: true,
    index: true
  }
});

JobSchema.index({ jobTitle: 'text'});

router.get('/search', async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const searchResults = await Job.find({$text: {$search: req.query.q }})
    console.log(searchResults);
    res.json({
      searchResults: searchResults
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({message: err});
  }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Try creating the index first in the shell or using compass and remove it from your code.

Answer (score 2):

Add `mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);` on your entry point file (app.js for example) after you required mongoose. 
e.g.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
```